# Javascript Set Var once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a Google chrome extension that when i click on it.

then the variable i will go up once and when i click again i want it to go up once more.
when Variable i equals 3 then i want to to set to 0 again.

I want to make a sort of switch.

**BACKGROUND.JS**

```
var i = 0;
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    i = i + 1
    if (i == 1) {
        var newURL = "http://www.website1.com";
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
            var newURL = "http://www.website2.com";
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
            var newURL = "http://www.website3.com";
        } elseif (i == 2) {
         chrome.tabs.close()
        } else {
         var i = 0
        }
    });
```

when i click on my Extension notification then it doesnt do anything at all.
and i think the chrome.tabs.close also doensnt work.

Comment: You missed a semicolon after `var i = 0;`. Also, please note that you should [check for errors in the console](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging). Instead of inspecting a popup like in that example, you need to inspect your background page.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = 0
```

Should be outside the function

Comment: @user3574561 Define "seems not to work". Did you reload your extension after that?

Comment: @user3574561 Okay, please edit the question to your latest version that includes this suggestion, and describe how it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is very simple. This is the correct answer. You have more bugs thou as your last if defines again the var at function level. Dont.